# date format change from string

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strtotime() doesn’t work with dd/mm/YYYY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

I have this variable which i get the info like this:

```
echo $start=$_REQUEST['to'];
```

It outputs something like this:

```
2/04/2012
```

What i need is to convert it like this: `20120402`
Could you please help me? I tried strotime and no success.. 
I tried converting the string before in a date format, then i converted it in a Ymd format, but i kept receiving a strange date, something like 1970 !
I tried this:

```
$time = strtotime( $date );
$myDate = date( 'y-m-d', $time );
```

thanks!

Comment: Please show complete code which does not work. Dates being formatted as 1970 typically means `strtotime` could not parse the date format and returned `0` == 1/1/1970. In your case `strtotime` does seem to parse the format correctly, and the `date` call should work just fine. The question is incoherent.

Comment: $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/02/2012'); $d->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead of `date`.

```
$myDate = strftime('%Y%m%d', $time);
```

Comment: In fact.. this worked for me :)
why - sign?

Comment: The difference between `strftime` and `date` is that `strftime` format date/time according to locale settings. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

It may work.

```
<?php
$start=$_REQUEST['to'];
$date = explode("/",$start);
$size = sizeof($date);
for($i=$size;$i>=0;$i--) {
    $date_get .= $date[$i];
}
echo $date_get;
?>
```