# Error in php date format conversion

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am the following code to convert this date -> `18/07/2013` to a `mysql` supported format.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('18/07/2013'));
```

Ideally this should return `2013-07-18`...
But, the problem is that it automatically selects the string as:
`YEAR as YEAR`
`MONTH as DAY`
`DAY as MONTH`

Now, because it identifies `18` as a `month`, it gets out of range and it shows the default date `1970-01-01`.

I have wasted almost two days on this thing.

If anyone can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: You could hack it as `strtotime(str_replace('/','-','18/07/2013'))`

Comment: Kindly use the search before posting a new question, this is a duplicate of [Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Comment: From the php manual -> YY "/" MM "/" DD this is what you are supposed to use with the date function... http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: @Prix I'll keep that in mind the next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :)

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '18/07/2013')));
```

Comment: Much appreciation.

Answer (score 5):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object, to get php understand in which format you passing date to it.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '18/07/2013');
echo $date ->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Isn't this for `PHP 5 >= 5.3.0` ? An older version of php is installed on my server.

Comment: @Safeer - Than i that case you need to do tweak as shown by andy & prix in comment.

Comment: Thanks Rikesh, that worked. Ayyappan's answer is quite good too :)

Answer (score 1):

strtotime parameter should be in format `18-07-2013`

Answer (score 1):

You need to [set the time zone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) of your date, **your date is being parsed as being American** and the American date format is mm/dd/yyyy...

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```

also use the [right reg. expression for the date function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

```
$date = date( 'YY "/" MM "/" DD', strtotime('18/07/2013'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash (/) means American M/D/Y formatting, a dash (-) means European D-M-Y and a period (.) means ISO Y.M.D.

Observe:

```
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11.12.10")); 
// outputs 10th December, 2011 

echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11/12/10")); 
// outputs 12th November, 2010 

echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11-12-10")); 
// outputs 11th December, 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with date string in PHP

> - Date values separated by slash are assumed to be in American order: m/d/y
> - Date values separated by dash are assumed to be in European order: d-m-y

Everything you wan to know about conversing date is below

http://shakalya.com/resolve-php-date-format-problem/

Comment: whats wrong here... ideally if you use 18/07/2013, first number is considered as MONTH But if you use 18-07-2013 then first number is a DAY. technically writing 18/07/2013 is wrong to write in PHP code because 18 cant be a month. SO change your naming convention according to codes. TO work with it change / with - then convert it to date.