# strtotime has issues because of date()

Tags: php

i have a problem with news script.

the code below will generate today's date, i think it's because that i have date() in the beggining, or maybe the line is just not written right.

the $postdate in the () is a numeric date, such as 13.11.01, again, i get the same date of today on all of the posts in the loop.
what's wrong with my line?

i need it to output the date as text one. such as December 13th, 2013

thanks

```
<?
$postdate = date('F jS, Y', strtotime($postdate));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that `strtotime()` doesn't recognize the `.` character as a valid separator. See below:

[Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 0):

First you have a typo on your question.

```
13.11.01 is November 1st, 2013 , Not November 13th, 2013
```

So, go the OOPway like this.

```
<?php
$dt='13.11.01';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y.m.d', $dt);
echo $datex= $date->format('F jS, Y'); //"prints" November 1st, 2013
```