# Sort a multidimensional array by sub key; Text keys disappears issue

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort this array by sub array key (10, 20, 21, 60, 70):

```
$array = array(
    'Value 1'=>  array (
        '10'=> "-11.34"
    ),

    "Value 2"=>  array (
        '60'=> '-10'
    ),

    "Value 3"=>  array (
        '70'=> '-23.96'
    ),

    "Value 4"=>  array (
        '20'=> '-23.96'
    ),

    "Value 5"=>  array (
        '21'=> '-6.1'
    )       
);
```

To get at the final this sorting:

> Value 1 : 11.34
>
> Value 4 : 20.4
>
> Value 5 : 6.1
>
> Value 2 : 10
>
> Value 3 : 23.96

Using this function:

```
function sortByValueKey($a, $b) {
    $keysA = array_keys($a);
    $keysB = array_keys($b);
    return $keysA[0] > $keysB[0];
}
```

I don't find my text values anymore. 
Any Ideas to solve this Issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a multidimentional array using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090227/sorting-a-multidimentional-array-using-php)

Comment: You should write more descriptive titles, so people can guess what do you need in a quick view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this code. $array is the content of your described array

```
<?php
function sortByValueKey($a, $b) {
    $keysA = array_keys($a);
    $keysB = array_keys($b);
    return $keysA[0] > $keysB[0];
}

uasort($array, 'sortByValueKey');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried it, but when I make a var_dump on my array I don't find my text values anymore (Value1, Value2...), any Ideas to fix that issue ?

Comment: fixed it! Just use uasort instead of usort!