# PHP date is always being returned as 01 January 1970 and strftime not translating

Tags: php, date, locale, strtotime, strftime

Ok, there's tons of questions about this and i try most of the solutions i found there without success.

I have a form passing a date in this format to the PHP function: `26/11/2014`

In the function i have to transform it in other forms and this is my code:

```
$date_1 = date('d F Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['date']));
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
$date_transl = strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['date']));
```

In both case i'm having returned `01 January 1970` so i'm facing 2 problems:

1) date returned is wrong

2) `strftime` is not translating the date

Comment: Try doing `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Or use `dd-mm-yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`... the slash indicates that the date should be treated as US format, the dash indicates European format, as described in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: `there's tons of questions about this` you are correct, and there is also a tons of answers on this, and your problem is the most common one!

Comment: possible duplicate of **[Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `/` characters with `-` and it will do the job:

```
$_REQUEST['date'] = str_replace('/','-',$_REQUEST['date']);
$date_1 = date('d F Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['date']));
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
$date_transl = strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['date']));
```

Comment: actually, i've noticed the month is not being translated anyway? even in my local language, it will be displayed in english while printing $date_1 (that is not being excplicitly localized)

Comment: Yes it will, `$date_transl` should contain the translated month name. If this isn't true, then probably your server doesn't recognize the language `de_DE`. I tried `nl_NL` and that worked properly.\

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$date_1 = date('d F Y', strtotime(str_replace('/','-','26/11/2014')));
```