# Convert date into a unix timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have a problem with my conversion. I don't understand where is my problem, because normally all will be work, So my conversion doesn't work.

```
$sEndDateFilter is 27/03/2015 23:59:59
```

When I tried to convert:

```
$iEndDateFilter = strtotime($sEndDateFilter);
```

my **$iEndDateFilter** is vide

Help me please.

Comment: try something  like this: strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '27/05/1990'));

Comment: This appears to be your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/strtotime   2nd last note> "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated...". You're using `/`, which implies m/d/y, but are passing in d/m/y

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
echo strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',"27/03/2015 23:59:59"));
```

You have to replace `/` with `-`

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

So, as Rizier suggests, a possible solution is to replace the slashes with dashes like this:

`echo strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',"27/03/2015 23:59:59"));`

Comment: He did but also the other was copied from the oficial documentation as this one refered

Comment: @TecBrat Now it's okay because you say: "hey if you read the manual here... you will see this..." Now it's a nice reference and answer why OP's code doesn't work! Maybe you can include an answer for OP how to solve this.

Comment: No matter if it was copied from the manual or from another question, the information is still useful here.