# Wrong output while converting to new date format

Tags: php

I have a string value "27/03/2015" and i want to convert this string to new date format. Below is the code i am using now.

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("27/03/2015")); ?>
```

But it gives a wrong output like this 1970-01-01.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',  YOUR DATE )))); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `strtotime` isn't being able to parse your date string.  Try:

```
<?php echo strtotime("27/03/2015"); ?>
```

The result should be `False`.  Since `False` is the same as `0`, you are really running `date("Y-m-d", 0)`, the result of which is "1970-01-01" (the "unix epoch").

`strtotime` only recognizes certain date formats, listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).  The closest to your input format is "27-03-2015" ("Day, month and four digit year, with dots, tabs or dashes").

Answer (score 0):

in above case / Seperator is not valid (as the date will be evaluated to Date 3 & Month 27)
you can use -

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("27-03-2015"));
```

Comment: `/` Yes it is valid!

Comment: @Rizier123 yes it is valid but with above input it will consider 3rd date and 27th month

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution

```
$date = '27/03/2015';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess "/" is not allowed or, should I say, unrecognizable as a parameter for strtotime.

```
<?php 
$dateString = "27/03/2015";
//now let's check if the variable has a "/" inside of it. 
//If it does, then replace "/" with "-". 
//If it doesnt, then go with it. 
//"." also accepted for strtotime as well.
$dateString = (strpos($dateString,"/") ? str_replace("/","-",$dateString) : $dateString);
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateString)); 
?>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).