# Issue with strtotime but the date/time looks valid

Tags: php

I have the following date "**25/01/2016 15:49:20**" as $my_time

Performing the following function on the date: `strtotime($my_time);` returns false. Now I have looked through other threads in relation to this, but from what I can garner this is a valid date/time for the `strtotime();` function. Could anyone suggest what the issue is here?

Comment: There is no 25th month. Basically that format is not valid. Use DateTime() to parse that date and get a Unix timestamp from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php, the format you have tried to specified is not valid. It is a mix between American month, day and year ("mm/dd/y") and Day, month and four digit year, with dots, tabs or dashes ("dd [.\t-] mm [.-] YY"). You can either switch the order of dd/mm or switch your "/" to "-".