# How can I format a date with php?

Tags: php

I am trying to format a date from my database:

```
$input = $data['date'];
$output = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($input));
```

The result is:

> $input: 2016-02-09 13:42:00
>
> $output: 01.01.1970

I do not understand, I am expecting the `$output` to be 09.02.2016

Comment: You should check what's inside `$data` cause it should be working

Comment: @Gwendal is right, $data['date'] appears to be incorrect. Try passing a string as $input, works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out

Comment: check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I need to write it like this:

```
$input = new DateTime($data['date']);
$output = $input->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: I was about to post it :) http://ideone.com/SSBUno Anyway it could be a language settings issue on the server.

Comment: This makes no sense. The problem was elsewhere. Not sure where the upvotes are coming from