# Convert 2017-03-01 to March 1st 2017 format inPHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to Convert `2017-03-01` to `March 1st 2017` format in PHP.

```
 $mark_entry_last_date=$exam_dates['last_date'];

 echo date('M j<\sup>S</\sup> Y', $mark_entry_last_date);
```

Above code outputs current date only but I need the date value for $mark_entry_last_date. How to get a result like March 1st 2017 for given date using escape characters. ?

Comment: Use `strtotime()` to `$mark_entry_last_date`, check [here](http://ideone.com/xcBEdU)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function expects second parameter to be timestamp (integer) not string, so you need to use `strtotime`:

```
echo date('M j<\s\up>S</\s\up> Y', strtotime($mark_entry_last_date));
```

Also you need to escape `u` for `sup` tag. Since `u` is format for displaying microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try without tags and use `strtotime()`

```
echo date("F jS Y", strtotime("2017-03-01"));  
// output March 1st 2017
```

For more http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php