# getTimeInMillis() in java

Tags: java, date

I have following piece of code, which is just calculating time in milliseconds for their respective date objects

```
     public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat APIformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM");
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         Date date = APIformatter.parse("01-23-2017 17:58:23");
         calendar.setTime(date);

         System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

         Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
         Date date2 = APIformatter.parse("01-24-2017 11:55:54");
         calendar2.setTime(date2);

         System.out.println(calendar2.getTimeInMillis());


    }
```

clearly `date2` is recent than `date` object, hence I expect that the value returned by `getTimeInMillis()` will be greater for `date2`  as compared to `date1`.
However that is not the case

```
System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis()); returning me 1634988600000
```

and

```
System.out.println(calendar2.getTimeInMillis());  returning me 1627104600000
```

clearly `date > date2` in returned values.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you notice that you provided a capital M for both *months* and *minutes* in your date format? `MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM`. Change it to `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt This is it....

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt please post this as answer, so we can upvote

Comment: You should use slashes(`MM/dd/yyyy`) instead of dashes (`MM-dd-yyyy`). I think it's more common. Most European countries use dashes, but with the day of the month preceding. PHP, for instance, will interpret dashes as of a European date, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2891949/507738).

Comment: Hi @nobalG I know what you are expecting but here the problem is when you are trying to parse your datetime then after parsing it returns a numeric value and clearly what we can see the 2 objects "date" and "date2" has values 23 and 24 respectively that means that "date2" value is one day after "date" value hence value of date > date2.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Missed your comment. The duplicate is fine though.