# PHP Date conversion output issue

Tags: php

I am trying to convert the format of this date **25/02/2017** to **2017-02-25**. 
I am using the PHP date function `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('25/02/2017'));` But the output i receive is **1970-01-01**. What should be the problem?

Comment: Well what does `strtotime('25/02/2017')` return?

Comment: @miken32 it gives 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2891937/1255289)

Comment: format passed to `date()` is invalid.Please check this:-https://eval.in/746825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/","-","25/02/2017")));
```