# Datepicker dd/mm/yy php and mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, date, datepicker

I have a problem with this code, when I try to use the dateformat dd/mm/yy it saves 1970/01/01 but when I use mm/dd/yy it works, I really dont know why here is the code I'm using:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="dateStart" class="datepicker">
```

JS

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); (Works)
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }); (Does not)
```

PHP

```
$date = isset($_POST['dateStart'])?date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_POST['dateStart']));
```

And the mysql column is a date field.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

-It´s a mysql datetime field

Comment: mysql date format should be Y-m-d

Comment: Can you please let us know what is your table field type? i mean is it `date` or `datetime`or `timestamps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can show convenient Format to user end But when you store it in database Mysql date Format should be 2017-05-24  'YYYY-MM-DD'

**JS**

`$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });`

2) And strtotime will not accept this date format 24/05/2017 seperated by slash so use string replace. and then change the format like this

**PHP**

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['dateStart']);
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use datepicker to show your users date in the desired format as you already have:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="dateStart" class="datepicker">
</form>
<script>
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
</script>
```

Then when you submit to PHP, you convert it so that you can store it correctly in the database:

```
<?php 

$date = $_POST['dateStart'];
$date_for_database = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
var_dump($date_for_database);
```

Comment: Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format  .i mean  separated by slash  format will not work .

Comment: @JYoThI I disagree. `strtotime('08/23/1994')`works. What makes you think it does not?

Comment: can you try this example echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('24/05/2017')); @CodeGodie

Comment: @JYoThI That wont work as `24/05/2017` is incorrect. It should be `05/24/2017` as they originally need.

Comment: the how it will work for this format "dd/mm/yy" as you suggested

Comment: same way `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('05/24/17'));`

Comment: dd/mm/yy"  will give this format of date  '05/24/17' ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['dateStart']);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reformat the date just post like what you want to save.

```
//mysql standard date format is: year-month-day
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
$date = isset($_POST['dateStart'])?date("m j Y",strtotime($_POST['dateStart']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [Stortime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) manual.

**Note:**

> m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['dateStart']);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

[Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)