# DateTime convert issue in php

Tags: php

I am converting date time into different formate but that code gives me wrong date time. I have show my code below

```
echo date('M d, Y h:i A', strtotime('25/05/19 05:59 AM')); die();
```

this code shows

```
Dec 31, 1969 06:00 PM
```

which is wrong can anybody help me in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) manual:

> **Note:**
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

So your date is invalid. You can work around this using [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) instead:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/y h:i A', '25/05/19 05:59 AM');
echo $date->format('M d, Y h:i A');
```

Output:

```
May 25, 2019 05:59 AM
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NRmFG)

Comment: a dash (-) signifies European D-M-Y and a period (.) signifies ISO Y.M.D. (-) and (.) both are different format.

Comment: @RasaMohamed what does that have to do with my answer?

Comment: minor change in your answer that's why commented for this `if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed`

Comment: @RasaMohamed the text is copied verbatim from the PHP manual; it's what the behaviour of `strtotime` is. If that happens to be different from other interpretations of `-` and `.`, that's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes I too referred from [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) if my first comment is not relevant then this `if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed` should not be in your answer RIGHT!. I don't want to drag this comments for silly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date('M d, Y h:i A', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '19/05/25 05:59 AM')));
```

Test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73d92119a368316a7c8d5af521319902c157b537

Comment: It's giving `May 19, 2025, 05:59 AM`, I think OP looking for `May 25, 2019, 05:59 AM`

Comment: Well, I just took the input what OP has described in the question. Maybe you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo date('M d, Y h:i A', strtotime('19-05-25 05:59 AM')); die();
```