# Having trouble wrapping my head around how to write a particular loop

Tags: php, sql, loops, output

I am querying a SQL database to return open work order operations.
My query is producing the Work Order number, operation status and due date.
I am trying to figure out how to iterate through the array that is returned and:

- Gather the sum of operations due within a week
- Gather the sum of operations due in the second week
- Continue to do this until I have made it through all of the entries, ongoing for as many weeks as necessary.

My SQL query looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM OPERATION WHERE RESOURCE_ID = '280LASERS' ORDER BY DUE_DATE;
```

It will return something like:

```
W/O #   | Setup Hours  |  Run Hours  |  Due Date
W159769 |     0.5      |    15.0     | 03/01/2020
W159770 |     1.5      |     9.0     | 04/01/2020
W159771 |     0.75     |    81.0     | 05/01/2020
```

Either way, what I am trying to accomplish is, query the database, step through my result and get the sum foreach week. 
 While NOW+7days <= DUE_DATE; While NOW+14days <= DUE_DATE...

Week One = 15.5 Hours; Week Two = 10.5 Hours; Week Three = 81.75 Hours
**EDIT:** I apologize for my mess of a question, this is one of the more intense tasks I have tried to accomplish with SQL and PHP. 

We are trying to get a better handle on our capacity, and reporting on our capacity.
I am hoping to be able to run a query that pulls all of the '280LASERS' Operations and have some sort of root value (Like todays Date) to compare the DUE_DATE against.
My plan is to sort by DUE_DATE and get the SUM(SETUP_HRS + RUN_HRS) until DUE_DATE is greater than (TODAY() + 7) then, get the SUM(SETUP_HRS + RUN_HRS) until DUE_DATE is greater than (TODAY() + 14) then ...
 I can't achieve this with static variables because the number of weeks can go from 6 weeks out, to more than 30 weeks out, simply depending on the DUE_DATE of the furthest out order.
I am so close I can taste it, I would really like to share my code, and the output... but feel I have blown this page up and it is a hot mess. Would it be acceptable for me to delete everything above this and reshare my code as it is, as well as the output I am getting.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the correlation between the due dates in your table example and the expected output. The due dates are a month apart. Did you mean to make them a week apart?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I'm back, I'll add a better commented code, here: can't edit the old answer, since I deleted my account and forgot to cancel :|

Anyways, you asked how to manipulate the data. It's a simple array and all the inner arrays are sums from the start of the week to the end. Now, you could store them with different keys, I just used the default assigning because of simplicity.

```
$results=array(
  array( 'due_date'=>'12/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>12.4, 'setup_hours'=>2.4, ),   //  2020-02-12 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'15/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>10.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),   //  2020-02-15 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'18/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>8.4, 'setup_hours'=>3.4, ),    //  2020-02-18 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'20/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>2.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),    //  2020-02-20 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'21/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),    //  2020-02-21 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'24/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>12.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),   //  2020-02-24 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'26/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>11.3, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),   //  2020-02-26 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'29/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>4.4, 'setup_hours'=>2.4, ),    //  2020-02-29 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'02/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>5.7, 'setup_hours'=>4, ),      //  2020-03-02 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'04/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>11.5, 'setup_hours'=>3.4, ),   //  2020-03-04 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'06/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>7.3, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),    //  2020-03-06 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'08/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.6, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),    //  2020-03-08 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'12/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>14.7, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),   //  2020-03-12 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'15/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>12.5, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),   //  2020-03-15 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'19/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>4.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),    //  2020-03-19 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'21/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>5.6, 'setup_hours'=>4, ),      //  2020-03-21 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'24/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>11.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),   //  2020-03-24 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'29/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>7.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),    //  2020-03-29 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'01/04/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),    //  2020-04-01 00:00:00

  // some far off weeks
  array( 'due_date'=>'18/06/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),
  array( 'due_date'=>'21/06/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),
  array( 'due_date'=>'09/07/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),
  array( 'due_date'=>'12/08/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ),


);
$time=strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // get time in same
// wrapping time in strtotime and date trims the seconds to the desired format

$one_week=60*60*24*7;
$sums=array();
foreach($results as $row){
/* php 5.3+ this block of code gets the time of the date, this conversions are made in case a custom non standard date format is made, alternatively one can use strtotime with the correct date format

 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['due_date']);//use your format and values
 if(!$date){
  echo 'Not a valid format';
  break;
 }
 $entry_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$date->getTimestamp()));
 // if your date format doesnt have hours minutes and seconds then timestamp will add the current h,min,s,
 // this may not be desired, so this wrapping it in strtotime and date trims the values
*/
 // WARNING:  If the format is right weeks will be way off
 $entry_time = strtotime($row['due_date']); // if due_date is a valid format, see PHP docs for more information
 if (!$entry_time) {
   echo "Not a valid date format";
   break;
 }
 $entry_work_hours=$row['run_hours']+$row['setup_hours'];
 // if the entry time is by some reason smaller then the current time save it to a special past_due container
 if ($entry_time < $time) {
   // if a past_due container exists add the sum, otherwise create a past_due container
   if (isset($sums['past_due'])) {
     $sums['past_due']['sum']+=$entry_work_hours;
   } else {
     $sums['past_due']= array(
      'sum'   => $entry_work_hours,
      'start' => $row['due_date'], // the earliest event
      'end'   => date('d/m/Y',$time), // current time, if $entry_time is bigger or equal we're talking about entries that are yet to happen
     );
   }
 } else if ( $entry_time >= $time ){
   // getting the future_dues array, every object holds an array/map, that holds the sum, the start of the week and when the week ends
   // endings are exclusive ie. if an entry_data falls on the end date it goes to the start of the next container
   if (isset($sums['future_dues'])) {
     $future_dues=$sums['future_dues'];
   } else {
     $future_dues = array(
       array(
         'sum'   => 0,
         'start' => $time,
         'end'   => $time+$one_week
       )
     );
   }
   // get the last week container, and save the key so we can reassign it back to the $sums array on the right spot
   $last_index = count($future_dues)-1;
   $future_due = $future_dues[$last_index];

   // manipulate the week data
   // if the entry time is smaller then the current end of the week add to the sum, otherwise add a new week interval container
   if ($entry_time < $future_due['end']) {
     $future_due['sum']+=$entry_work_hours;
     // reassign week container
     $future_dues[$last_index]=$future_due;
   } else {
     $last_week_end = $future_due['end'];
     $new_end       = $last_week_end + $one_week;

     //do a while loop to get the next week end in which the work is done
     while ($new_end < $entry_time) {
       // skip this part if empty weeks are not desired
       $future_dues[] = array(
         'sum'   => 0,
         'start' => $last_week_end,
         'end'   => $new_end
       );
       $last_week_end = $new_end;
       $new_end       = $new_end + $one_week;
       // echo "$new_end < $entry_time".'<br>';
     }

     // add a new week container, the start of the week is the end of the previous one and the end is 7 days from that
     $future_dues[]=array(
       'sum'   => $entry_work_hours,
       'start' => $last_week_end,
       'end'   => $new_end
     );
   }
   // reassign the whole week containers container to the array
   $sums['future_dues']=$future_dues;
 }
}
// convert time back to dates
foreach ($sums['future_dues'] as $key => &$due) {
  $due['start']=date('d/m/Y',$due['start']);
  $due['end']=date('d/m/Y',$due['end']);
}

// use $sums to display the values you need, use:
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($sums);
// echo "</pre>";
// to better understand how data is stored


echo "<pre>"; // use pre tags to have a nice inline values, this can be rewriten into a table
$past_due=$sums['past_due'];
//past due is a single container
$time_prefix="Time: ";
$working_hours_prefix="Working hours: ";

$time = $time_prefix.$sums['past_due']['start']." - ".$sums['past_due']['end'];
echo $time."<br>";
echo $working_hours_prefix.str_pad($sums['past_due']['sum'],abs(strlen($time)-strlen($working_hours_prefix)),' ',STR_PAD_LEFT);
// make it inline with the time
echo "<br><br>";

$due_dates=$sums['future_dues'];
foreach($due_dates as $week_container){
  $time = $time_prefix.$week_container['start']." - ".$week_container['end'];
  echo $time."<br>";
  echo $working_hours_prefix.str_pad($week_container['sum'],abs(strlen($time)-strlen($working_hours_prefix)),' ',STR_PAD_LEFT);
  echo "<br><br>";

  //echo $week_container['sum'];      /// if you want to show the sum
  //echo $week_container['start'];    /// if you want to show the start
  //echo $week_container['end'];      /// if you want to show the end
}
echo "</pre>";
// above is a bit abstracted but it esencially does this


echo "<br><br>";
echo "<br><br>";

$past_due=$sums['past_due'];

$past_start = $sums['past_due']['start'];
$past_end   = $sums['past_due']['end'];
$past_sum   = $sums['past_due']['sum'];

echo "Time: $past_start - $past_end<br>";
echo "Working hours: $past_sum"; // previous case adds breaks to be inline
echo "<br><br>";

$due_dates=$sums['future_dues'];
foreach($due_dates as $week_container){

  $week_start = $week_container['start'];
  $week_end   = $week_container['end'];
  $week_sum   = $week_container['sum'];

  echo "Time: $week_start - $week_end<br>";
  echo "Working hours: $week_sum"; // previous case adds breaks to be inline
  echo "<br><br>";

}
```

Edit:
A new while loop was added to account for empty weeks.
Note d/m/Y is not strtotime recognised format and it will be read as m/d/Y. To convert [it refer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

Edit-2:
To answer your comment. Ok so the thing about the spans is that I made them so that if the span went from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-08 and the second one from 2020-01-08 to 2020-01-15 where should the working hours of 2020-01-08 go to week 1 or week 2? 
When you corrected $entry_time < $future_due['end'] to $entry_time <= $future_due['end'] this means that the count is added to week 1, while the original solution would have added it to week 2 as the starting date.

You can try and add 8 days and then subtract one if you wanted the containers to span between 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-08 and 2020-01-09 and 2020-01-16 and have both endings be inclusive. Now, I'm not going to write this part since it really depends on how YOU want define your endings.

And your question if you can change the time to something else then the current time? Sure, just change this line.

```
$time=strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

//to

$time=__TIME__YOU_WANT_IN_SECONDS__;

//or

$time = strtotime(__THE_DATE_YOU_WANT__); // eg. 01/01/2020
// now this is the time to compare all other dates to
```

Comment: Thanks again for the response, that code is some awesome work. The only place I am running into trouble is with the weeks that have no value yet. For instance, we have orders in already for 6/4/2020 but none between 4/30/2020 and 6/3/2020 so the out put for the weeks in between still outputs (it doesn't skip empty weeks) and will pull the first entry from the next scheduled week, causing many issues. So, I can use the data up until that point, but then it is all incorrect.

Comment: Aha ok I see give me a minute or two

Comment: Hey, what would cause the day to be off by one? It says it is ending on 03/06 yet it is actually ending on 03/05. I think I need a +1 somewhere but can't see it.

Comment: P.S. It seems to fix itself after that first iteration, so the PAST DUE is correct, the first week span is -1 day, the second week span is +1 day, then all the numbers on the proceeding weeks are correct.

Comment: I DID IT! The issue was with this line : if ($entry_time < $future_due['end']) {.... I changed it to if ($entry_time <= $future_due['end']) {.... And it now correctly captures the final day of each week before moving on!

Comment: Is it possible to do something along the lines of: If TODAY - 01/01/2020 is DIVISIBLE by 6 $last_index = count(future_dues) - 6; ELSE IF is divisible by 5 $last_index = count(future_dues) - 5;

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a loop. It looks like you could just calculate the week number, group by that, and sum the hours for the week.

**MySQL**

```
select
  DATEDIFF(due_date, NOW()) DIV 7 + 1 AS week_number,
  SUM(setup_hours + run_hours) AS week_hours
from operation
where resource_id = '280LASERS'
group by week_number;
```

**SQL Server**

```
select
  DATEDIFF(wk, getdate(), due_date) AS week_number,
  SUM(setup_hours + run_hours) AS week_hours
from operation
where resource_id = '280LASERS'
group by DATEDIFF(wk, getdate(), due_date);
```

Comment: I am trying to execute this code in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I am getting this error: "'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Okay, I swapped NOW() for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and am getting DATEDIFF requires 3 arguments.

Comment: Okay, I changed that line to "DATEDIFF(week, WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS week_number" and I am slowly getting somewhere.

Comment: Oh, oops, it's SQL Server. I had assumed MySQL since it is so often with PHP. I'd recommend tagging your database-related questions with the specific system you're using.

Comment: I wish I could have figured out how to convert this and get it to work as this is MUCH cleaner and simpler. Thank you for your input!

Comment: I may be able to make a version of it for sql server. Just haven't had time yet today to look at it again

Comment: @Justin.MPC I added a different example query to the answer for SQL server

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your awesome help

Answer (score 1):

As Don't Panic pointed out about the due dates, I think you might be displaying it in a dd/mm/YYYY format and I'll work from there.
I'll work with a foreach loop but I think Don't Panic's solution might be more efficient.

Steps:
1. Loop through the values and calculate the time of the date,
2. Compare it with the desired date
3. Add it to the right sum

Notes: date format is important, if hours, minutes and seconds are missing the getTimestamp adds the current values for them

I've added some test data based on my understanding of the problem.

I've also added a past due column in case any date is already past the current time().

The foreach loop checks the if the entry_time is smaller than the current time, this means it is past_due.

If not, we check if the future_dues are set. Future dues represent all the different weeks in the future. If none are set one array with an array is added. 
The second array represent the current closest future starting from the current time to the end of 7 days in the future.

Start and end help us read the end results better, they are timestamps. Also a sum key of value 0 is added.

Then we take the last element from the future_dues and see if the due_date is smaller then the end of the week. If it is we add the working hour, otherwise we add a new future_due object.

At the end I added a foreach loop that converts the timestamps to a date format.

```
$results=array(
  array( 'due_date'=>'12/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>12.4, 'setup_hours'=>2.4, ), //  2020-02-12 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'15/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>10.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-02-15 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'18/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>8.4, 'setup_hours'=>3.4, ), //  2020-02-18 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'20/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>2.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-02-20 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'21/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-02-21 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'24/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>12.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-02-24 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'26/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>11.3, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-02-26 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'29/02/2020', 'run_hours'=>4.4, 'setup_hours'=>2.4, ), //  2020-02-29 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'02/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>5.7, 'setup_hours'=>4, ), //  2020-03-02 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'04/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>11.5, 'setup_hours'=>3.4, ), //  2020-03-04 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'06/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>7.3, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-03-06 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'08/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.6, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-03-08 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'12/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>14.7, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-03-12 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'15/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>12.5, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-03-15 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'19/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>4.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-03-19 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'21/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>5.6, 'setup_hours'=>4, ), //  2020-03-21 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'24/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>11.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-03-24 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'29/03/2020', 'run_hours'=>7.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-03-29 00:00:00
  array( 'due_date'=>'01/04/2020', 'run_hours'=>9.4, 'setup_hours'=>1.4, ), //  2020-04-01 00:00:00

);
$time=strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // get time in same
// wrapping time in strtotime and date trims the seconds to the desired format

$one_week=60*60*24*7;
$sums=array();
foreach($results as $row){
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['due_date']);//use your format and values
 if(!$date){
  echo 'Not a valid format';
  break;
 }
 $entry_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$date->getTimestamp()));
 // if your date format doesnt have hours minutes and seconds then timestamp will add the current h,min,s,
 // this may not be desired, so this wrapping it in strtotime and date trims the values
 $entry_work_hours=$row['run_hours']+$row['setup_hours'];
 if ($entry_time < $time) {
   if (isset($sums['future_dues'])) {
     $sums['past_due']['sum']+=$entry_work_hours;
   } else {
     $sums['past_due']= array(
      'sum'=> $entry_work_hours,
      'start'=> $row['due_date'],
      'end' => date('d/m/Y',$time),
     );
   }
 } else if ( $entry_time > $time ){
   if (isset($sums['future_dues'])) {
     $future_dues=$sums['future_dues'];
   } else {
     $future_dues = array(
       array(
         'sum'=>0,
         'start'=>$time,
         'end'=>$time+$one_week
       )
     );
   }
   $last_index = count($future_dues)-1;
   $future_due = $future_dues[$last_index];
   if ($entry_time < $future_due['end']) {
     $future_due['sum']+=$entry_work_hours;
     $future_dues[$last_index]=$future_due;
   } else {
     $future_dues[]=array(
       'sum'=>$entry_work_hours,
       'start'=>$future_due['end'],
       'end'=>$future_due['end']+$one_week
     );
   }
   $sums['future_dues']=$future_dues;
 }
}
// if you want to conver them back to dates
foreach ($sums['future_dues'] as $key => &$due) {
  $due['start']=date('d/m/Y',$due['start']);
  $due['end']=date('d/m/Y',$due['end']);
}
```

Comment: Hey there, I appreciate your response, I am reading through this and trying to comprehend it all, I will reply when I get finished. Thanks again!

Comment: So, I think I got it figured out, I plugged in all of my info. I just am not sure where I need to echo from, to get some results posted to the page...

Comment: Okay, I could use some help, I have PHP 5.2.1, didn't know that would be an issue, most of your code is incompatible (i.e. DateTime::createFromFormat). Is it possible for you to provide the alternative to that code?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Code seems to get me some good info, here is the final version
`SELECT
    DATEDIFF(week, getdate(), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE) AS week_number,
    SUM(OPERATION.SETUP_HRS + OPERATION.RUN_HRS) AS week_hours
FROM OPERATION
JOIN WORK_ORDER ON OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID
WHERE OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID = '103TURRET' AND (OPERATION.STATUS = 'R' OR OPERATION.STATUS = 'F') AND WORK_ORDER.SUB_ID = '0'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(week, getdate(), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)
ORDER BY week_number;`

Gives Me

```
week_number    week_hours
-14              0.630
-11              1.640
-8               1.980
-1               0.540
0                3.820
1                18.500
2                15.090
3                3.410
5                16.490
7                0.890
9                17.950
14               5.000
19               5.000
23               6.750
27               5.000
31               5.000
```

I manually total the negatives + zero week = past due

Thank you very much @*Don't Panic* for all of your help.

Ehh... if anyone could help me get this to where it always starts on a Monday, rather than the day it is run, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, here is the code I have so far. I would like to get it to look better, maybe not show all the different elements in the array... but I am terrified to change much more.

This is some pretty incredible code as far as I am concerned.

```
<?php //CONNECTION SETTING
  $database='VMFG';
  $odbc_name='SQLServer';
  $odbc_user='sa';
  $odbc_password='Password#';
  $con = odbc_connect($odbc_name,$odbc_user,$odbc_password);

  $query="SELECT  OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AS 'W/O #', /*STATEMENT TO PULL OPERATIONS AND PARSE WORK ORDER DATES*/
      OPERATION.WORKORDER_SUB_ID AS 'SUB ID',
      OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID AS 'RESOURCE ID',
      OPERATION.SETUP_HRS AS 'SETUP HRS',
      OPERATION.RUN AS 'RUN RATE',
      OPERATION.RUN_TYPE AS 'U/M',
      OPERATION.RUN_HRS AS 'RUN TOTAL',
      OPERATION.CALC_START_QTY AS 'START QTY',
      OPERATION.CALC_END_QTY AS 'END QTY',
      OPERATION.COMPLETED_QTY AS 'QTY COMP',
      OPERATION.DEVIATED_QTY AS 'DIFFERENCE',
      OPERATION.ACT_SETUP_HRS AS 'SETUP USED',
      OPERATION.ACT_RUN_HRS AS 'HRS RUN',
      OPERATION.STATUS,
      OPERATION.SETUP_COMPLETED AS 'SETUP COMP',
      WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE AS 'DUE DATE'
      FROM OPERATION
      JOIN WORK_ORDER ON OPERATION.WORKORDER_BASE_ID=WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID
      WHERE (OPERATION.STATUS = 'R' OR OPERATION.STATUS = 'F')
      AND (OPERATION.RESOURCE_ID = '".$_GET['operation']."')
      AND WORK_ORDER.SUB_ID = '0'
      ORDER BY STATUS DESC, [DUE DATE];";
?>

<form method="get">                     <?//FORM TO CHOOSE OPERATION?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="operation">
            <option value="103TURRET">103TURRET</option>
            <option value="104PRESSBRAKES">104PRESSBRAKES</option>
            <option value="280LASERS">280LASERS</option>
            <option value="300WELD">300WELD</option>
            <option value="701POWDERLINE">701POWDERLINE</option>
            <option value="Outside Service">Outside Server</option>
            <option value="ANYOSS">ANY OSS</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action" /></td>
      <td><a href='index.php'>Start Over</a></td>
      <td><a href='/xampp/mpc_db/index.php'>Return to DB</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<?php
$exec = odbc_exec($con, $query);
$results = array();
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($exec)) {
  $results[] = $row;
}
//*****************************************************************
$time=strtotime(date('Y/m/d')); // get time in same
//wrapping time in strtotime and date trims the seconds to the desired format

$one_week=604800;
$sums=array();
foreach($results as $row){
  /*$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $row['DUE DATE']);//use your format and values*/
  $date = date($row['DUE DATE']);

if(!$date){
  echo 'Not a valid format';
  break;
}  
$entry_time = strtotime(date('Y/m/d',strtotime($date)));
// if your date format doesnt have hours minutes and seconds then timestamp will add the current h,min,s,
// this may not be desired, so this wrapping it in strtotime and date trims the values
$entry_work_hours=$row['RUN TOTAL']+$row['SETUP HRS'];

if ($entry_time < $time) {
if (isset($sums['past_due'])) {
 $sums['past_due']['sum'] += $entry_work_hours;
 } else {
 $sums['past_due'] = array(
  'sum'=> $entry_work_hours,
  'start'=> $row['due_date'],
  'end' => date('Y/m/d',$time),
 );
}
} else if ( $entry_time > $time ){
if (isset($sums['future_dues'])) {
 $future_dues=$sums['future_dues'];
} else {
 $future_dues = array(
   array(
     'sum'=>0,
     'start'=>$time,
     'end'=>$time+$one_week
   )
 );
}
$last_index = count($future_dues)-1;
$future_due = $future_dues[$last_index];
if ($entry_time < $future_due['end']) {
 $future_due['sum']+=$entry_work_hours;
 $future_dues[$last_index]=$future_due;
} else {
 $future_dues[]=array(
   'sum'=>$entry_work_hours,
   'start'=>$future_due['end'],
   'end'=>$future_due['end']+$one_week
 );
}
$sums['future_dues']=$future_dues;
}
}

// if you want to convert them back to dates
foreach ($future_dues as $key => &$due) {
  $due['start']=date('Y/m/d',$due['start']);
  $due['end']=date('Y/m/d',$due['end']);
}

//**********************************************************************
foreach($sums['past_due'] as $stuff){ //Actually kind-of sort-of********
  print_r($stuff);                    //Looks like exactly**************
  echo "<br>";                        //What I am trying to create******
}                                     //Past Due Hours!*****************
//**********************************************************************

//**********************************************************************
foreach($future_dues as $edues){  //Actually kind-of sort-of************
  print_r($edues);                //Looks like exactly******************
  echo "<br>";                    //What I am trying to create**********
}                                 //Future Hours!***********************
//**********************************************************************

?>
```

The best part is! My output is readable!

```
5.26

2020/02/27
Array ( [sum] => 9.26 [start] => 2020/02/27 [end] => 2020/03/05 )
Array ( [sum] => 7.31 [start] => 2020/03/05 [end] => 2020/03/12 )
Array ( [sum] => 6.27 [start] => 2020/03/12 [end] => 2020/03/19 )
Array ( [sum] => 2.14 [start] => 2020/03/19 [end] => 2020/03/26 )
Array ( [sum] => 11.82 [start] => 2020/03/26 [end] => 2020/04/02 )
Array ( [sum] => 6.95 [start] => 2020/04/02 [end] => 2020/04/09 )
Array ( [sum] => 36 [start] => 2020/04/09 [end] => 2020/04/16 )
Array ( [sum] => 0.81 [start] => 2020/04/16 [end] => 2020/04/23 )
Array ( [sum] => 30.98 [start] => 2020/04/23 [end] => 2020/04/30 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.3 [start] => 2020/04/30 [end] => 2020/05/07 )
Array ( [sum] => 3.29 [start] => 2020/05/07 [end] => 2020/05/14 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.57 [start] => 2020/05/14 [end] => 2020/05/21 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.95 [start] => 2020/05/21 [end] => 2020/05/28 )
Array ( [sum] => 0.29 [start] => 2020/05/28 [end] => 2020/06/04 )
Array ( [sum] => 2.19 [start] => 2020/06/04 [end] => 2020/06/11 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.57 [start] => 2020/06/11 [end] => 2020/06/18 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.95 [start] => 2020/06/18 [end] => 2020/06/25 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.3 [start] => 2020/06/25 [end] => 2020/07/02 )
Array ( [sum] => 3.29 [start] => 2020/07/02 [end] => 2020/07/09 )
Array ( [sum] => 0.67 [start] => 2020/07/09 [end] => 2020/07/16 )
Array ( [sum] => 0.33 [start] => 2020/07/16 [end] => 2020/07/23 )
Array ( [sum] => 2.73 [start] => 2020/07/23 [end] => 2020/07/30 )
Array ( [sum] => 17.79 [start] => 2020/07/30 [end] => 2020/08/06 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.57 [start] => 2020/08/06 [end] => 2020/08/13 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.95 [start] => 2020/08/13 [end] => 2020/08/20 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.3 [start] => 2020/08/20 [end] => 2020/08/27 )
Array ( [sum] => 3.29 [start] => 2020/08/27 [end] => 2020/09/03 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.3 [start] => 2020/09/03 [end] => 2020/09/10 )
Array ( [sum] => 3.29 [start] => 2020/09/10 [end] => 2020/09/17 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.57 [start] => 2020/09/17 [end] => 2020/09/24 )
Array ( [sum] => 1.95 [start] => 2020/09/24 [end] => 2020/10/01 )
```

Although I can not figure out how to manipulate it without breaking it...