# How to get the complex value from the date/time in string

Tags: php

There are two different methods of time that the API response back. I'm looking for the date format in PHP that can bring the Unix timeStamp same.

```
$d = strtotime("Thu Jun 17 01:18:07 PKT 2021");
$t=strtotime("17/06/2021 01:18 AM");
```

the above should revert similar unix timeStamp

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: use `mktime()` method.

Comment: `d/m` is not valid.  Either use `06/17` or `17-06`

Comment: the payment API returns the above parameters in JSON. I wanted to convert the time so that can be used as a transaction id.  there are two json response for 1 payment but differnet date style. I need if I can convert both to unix timestamp to use as timestamp to check invoice duplication

Comment: @FaizanAli do I need to explode the time then mktime ?